# XAML not rendering when using Windows phone toolkit

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, expression-blend

I am developing an application. I downloaded the Windows phone toolkit for using the phonetextbox. When i try to create a phone text box control, the control is not rendering in the XAML designer. But it is running in the emulator or phone. I am using Visual studio 2013 community edition

What might be the problem?

Comment: there is no "Community Edition" for 2013, only for 2015. Can you tell us what error do you see?